# Python read txt file from url and write it line by line

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a text file in webserver with a list of ids and want to download it to local computer using python Im using below code

```
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11'}
    url = "http://example.com/ids.txt"
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = page.read()
    self.debug(content)
    filename = "ids.txt"
    file_ = open(filename, 'w')
    file_.write(content)
    file_.close()
```

but using this way i can only get first Id not the rest of it. e.g my web file contains

```
1
2
3
4
```

and im only geting

```
1
```

using above code

Comment: yes it is for Forbidden 403 error

Comment: and what that does ?

Comment: you are not making any sense you are telling me what i already using for. you asked me why im using hdr i said to avoid 403 forbidden error and you are showing me same answer. I have file write issue please can you help me on that ?

Comment: i know that :P I dont need those parameter thats why im not using.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind this is for Python 3:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
file = open("filename","w")
url = urlopen("url")
for line in url:
    file.write(line + '\n')
file.close()
```

For Python 2:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
url = urlopen("url")
file = open("filename", "w")
for line in url:
    file.write(line + '\n')
file.close()
```

easiest way is to use the Urllib libraries for this.

Comment: I dont want to print i want to download it.

Comment: ohhh then thats abit different, let me edit my comment.

Comment: Anyways my above code works fine it was just my url issue. FIXED

Answer (score 0):

My own code works good it was just an URL issue.

Comment: lol, just delete the question before you get negative points lol